# Showing $\lim_{ x \to \infty}\int_0^\infty\frac{t e^{-xt}}{1-e^t}dt=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Showing that the $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}V(x) = 0$

where $$V(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{te^{-xt}}{(1-e^t)}dt$$

This integral is between 0 and infinity.

I know this is quite straight forward, but I'm trying to get my head around this question. Do I have to integrate V(x) in terms of t, followed by limiting x to infinity, or is there a simpler way to go about this, as this is quite a tricky integral!

Comment: Is the integral definite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $x>0$. One may just use the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), we have

- $$ \left|\int_0^\infty\frac{t e^{-xt}}{e^t-1}dt\right|\leq
     \int_0^\infty\frac{t }{e^t-1}dt<\infty $$

  and
- $$ \lim_{ x \to \infty}\frac{t e^{-xt}}{e^t-1}=0. $$

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$e^t\ge 1+t\implies \frac{t}{e^t-1}\le1$$
hence

$$\vert V(x)\vert\le\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}dt=\frac1x$$
and conclude using the squeeze theorem.